# How to access contents of OneNote Page?

Tags: powershell, onenote

I'm new to powershell, and have gotten this far looking for code examples online, however I'm unable to find any examples that show me how to get at the actual page contents of a OneNote page with Powershell.

```
$OneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
[xml]$Hierarchy = ""
$OneNote.GetHierarchy("", 
[Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages, [ref]$Hierarchy)

foreach ($notebook in $Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook ) {
    $notebook.Name
    "=============="
    foreach ($section in $notebook.Section) {
    "# TAB: " + $section.Name
        foreach ($page in $section.page) {
            "   " + $page.Name
            #$page.GetAttribute.ToString()
            #$page.Attributes
            #$page.InnerText
            # How do I get to the contents of the page?
        }
    }
    " "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I was looking for a solution today on how to read OneNote notebook contents using powershell, I was initially pleased that I found this article here. But then I didn't get any further at first because I kept getting an error; namely in the line

```
Select-Xml -xml($xml.Value) -Namespace $schema -Xpath "//one:Notebook/one:Section" |foreach{
```

It always said that `$xml.Value` has the value `NULL`, and it cannot be cast to the type `XmlNode[]`.

After some trial and error, I found that all I had to do was simply change this line to

```
Select-Xml -xml $xml -Namespace $schema -Xpath "//one:Notebook/one:Section" |foreach{
```

so just omit the `.Value` and the surrounding brackets.

And yes, of course: Thanks to the article creator! I would never have come up with this solution on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Seeing that OneNote content is within an `XMLElement`. you will need to use `Select-Xml` to get the information.

Below is an example of how to get the `Page` property of the `XMLElement`:

```
$OneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
$schema = @{one=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote”}
[xml]$Hierarchy = ""
$OneNote.GetHierarchy("", 
[Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages, [ref]$Hierarchy)

foreach ($notebook in $Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook ) {
    $notebook.Name
    "=============="
    foreach ($section in $notebook.Section) {    
        foreach ($page in $section.page) {
            "   " + $page
            foreach($xml in $page)
            {
               Select-Xml -xml($xml.Value) -Namespace $schema -Xpath "//one:Notebook/one:Section" |foreach{
                $node = $psitem.node
                $npath = Split-Path -Path $node.Path -Parent
                #This is where all the magic happens
                $props = [ordered]@{
                    Workbook= Split-Path -Path $npath -Leaf
                    Section = $node.name
                    Child = $node.ChildNodes
                    Page = $node.Page #This is your page content
                }
                New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
               }


            }            
        }
    }

}
```